# Approximated second derivative

Tags: approximation, education

Approximated second derivative of $y(0)''$ function $y(x)$ at x = 0 difference quotient, using the values ​​of $y(x)$ at the sites of the three-point template $ {x}_{1} = \frac {-4h} { 5}, {x} _ {2} = 0, {x} _ {3} = \frac {h} {5} $.

Calculate the difference quotient value (approximate value of $y '' (0)$) for $ y (x) = {x} ^ {3} $ when $h = 0.05$. The result is rounded to hundredths.

Decision:

$y''= \frac{{y} _ {i +1} -2 {y} _ {i} + {y} _ {i-1}} {{h} ^ { 2}}$

$y _ {i + 1} = {\frac {-4 (0.05)} {5}} ^ {3}$

$y _ {i} = 0$

$y _ {i-1} = {\frac {(0.05)} {5}} ^ {3}$

=> $y'' = - 0.03$

The obvious answer is $-0.03$.

But the authors insist that the answer is $-0.06$.

Please help me understand where they got the multiplication by $2$ ? I can not understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! First take the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not your intenetion, please [edit] your question to make it explicitly about Wolfram Mathematica programming. Include a [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) minimum example of the code you are working on

Comment: Notice that the data points provided are not equally spaced! $m_i= \Delta y_i/ \Delta x_i$ and $\Delta x_i$ is not always the same. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ppmYS.png